# Sin in radians or degrees in Xin-She Yang N. 4 Function?

Tags: trigonometry

I have to solve the [Xin-She Yang N. 4 Function](http://benchmarkfcns.xyz/benchmarkfcns/xinsheyangn4fcn.html) using [Evolution Strategies](http://Evolution%20strategy).

This is the function:

$f(\bar x)=f(x_1, ..., x_n)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin^2(x_i)-e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}\right)e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sin^2\sqrt{|x_i|}}}$

There are two $\sin$ in the function.

How can I know if the values $x_1, ..., x_n$ are in degrees or radians?

Comment: Thanks for down voting and don't telling why.

Comment: The angles are in radians unless specified otherwise. Btw, I didn't downvote your post.

Comment: Downvoting is like punishing my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any math beyond basic trig the arguments of trig functions are in radians.  The only advantage of degrees is that simple angles come out with simple whole numbers of degrees.  This does not compensate for the unnatural derivatives, integrals, Taylor series, etc. that come from degrees.  You could certainly define $y_i=\frac {180}{\pi}x_i$ and write your sine functions in degrees if you want.

Comment: Thanks. I want to learn maths. I have another question. The function can be defined on any input domain but it is usually evaluated on $x_i in [-10, 10]$ for $i=1, …, n$. Does it mean that -10 and 10 are radians? I asked because $x_i$ in $\sum$. Sorry, but I'm a little confuse with this function.

Comment: Rereading in light of your comment, the $x_i$ should be viewed as real numbers, not as angles.  If you evaluate your function on a calculator it should be in radian mode.  $\sin (x)$ can be defined as a function of $x$ without any reference to angles, as the Taylor series or as one of the solutions to the differential equation $y''+y=0$  It agrees with the angle definition when the angles are in radians.

Comment: Thanks. So, I don't need to convert $x$ to radians, isn't it?

Comment: No, and you should stop thinking about the argument to $\sin$ as an angle.  You don't think of the argument to $\exp$ as an angle and we have the relation $\sin x = \frac 12(\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix))$.  Yes, when given an angle in radians as an argument $\sin$ tells us useful things about triangles, but it comes up in many other contexts.  The one you are asking about looks like one.  I don't know how the formula was derived, but I bet the $x_i$ are not angles.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I have understood it.